# Utilizar un espacio o " " como elemento de un string en c++

Tags: c++

Quiero tener un espacio como elemento de un string en c++

este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();
int cont=1;
while(n--){
    cout<<"Message #"<<cont<<endl;;
    string mensaje[2000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i){
        mensaje[i]="0";

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){

        cin>>mensaje[i];
        if(mensaje[i]!="0"){
            cout<<"["<<mensaje[i]<<"]";
        }

    }

    cont++;
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

y cuando hago la prueba con un archivo de texto a meter desde la terminal en linux digamos   ./ejemplo < ejemplo.txt

Este es el archivo de texto:

```
2
... --- ...
.--- --- -...  -.. --- -. .  ..--..  ..-. .. -. . -.-.--
```

me imprime esto:

`Message #1
[...][---][...][.---][---][-...][-..][---][-.][.][..--..][..-.][..][-.][.][-.-.--]
Message #2`

y yo lo necesito:

`Message #1
[...][ ][---][ ][...]
Message #2 
[.---][ ][---][ ][-...][ ][ ][-..][ ][---][ ][-.][ ][.][ ][ ][..--..][ ][..-.][ ][..][ ][-.][ ][.][ ][-.-.--]`

gracias por su colaboración.

---

Perdona no haberlo especificado antes, estoy resolviendo el ejercicio 11223 de uva y por ello requiero de los 2000 strings, y necesito saber cuando hay espacios o no porque necesito hacer una especie de traductor de codigo morse, y el espacio es para identificar si es otra letra y si son dos espacios seguidos son un espacio en el ya traducido morse.

Comment: Si quieres usar `std::string` debes cambiar la cabecera `<string.h>` por `<string>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu código no tiene sentido, seguramente has confundido algunos conceptos de C++.

---

La línea:

```
string mensaje[2000];
```

Crea dos mil objetos de tipo `std::string` inicializados al valor por defecto (es decir: vacíos); supongo que estabas pensando que creabas un solo objeto de texto capaz de contener dos mil caracteres... pero no puedo saber tus intenciones con certeza, puedo equivocarme.

Este bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i){
    mensaje[i]="0";
```

Hace que todas las cadenas de texto de tu formación `mensaje` contengan la cadena `"0"`, podías haber conseguido el mismo efecto con un `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> mensaje(2000, std::string{"0"});
```

Este otro bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    cin>>mensaje[i];
    if(mensaje[i]!="0"){
        cout<<"["<<mensaje[i]<<"]";
    }
}
```

Te captura datos con formato desde la consola. El operador de extracción de la consola ([`>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)) hace lectura de datos y considera que los datos estarán separados por espacios, lo que entiendo en tu pregunta es que esperas que los datos estén separados por líneas y luego separar cada línea por espacios; para eso usa [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string m;
while (std::getline(std::cin, m)){
    if(m!="0"){
        cout<<"["<<m<<"]\n";
    }
}
```

Con esto tu salida debería pasar a ser:

> ```
> [... --- ...]
> [.--- --- -...  -.. --- -. .  ..--..  ..-. .. -. . -.-.--]
> ```

Que aún no es lo que necesitas; pero sabiendo que la extracción se hace considerando el espacio como separador podrías usar un [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) sobre los datos extraídos:

```
std::stringstream ss(linea);
if (ss >> linea) {
    std::cout << '[' << linea << ']';
    while (ss >> linea)
        std::cout << "[ ][" << linea << ']';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Si además, confías en el límite de datos de entrada (en lugar de comprobar que has leído `"0"`), eliminas las variables innecesarias y olvidas tu (innecesaria) formación de 2000 cadenas tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   // string.h no es una cabecera de C++, usa string
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int mensajes; // Leer la cantidad de mensajes a recibir
    std::string linea;
    std::cin >> mensajes;
    std::cin.ignore();

    // Por cada mensaje esperado, leemos una línea
    for (int mensaje = 0; (mensaje != mensajes) && std::getline(std::cin, linea); ++mensaje) {
        std::cout << "Message #" << (mensaje + 1) << '\n';

        // Pasamos la línea a un stream de texto
        std::stringstream ss(linea);
        // Leemos dato a dato hasta llegar a final del stream de texto
        if (ss >> linea) {
            std::cout << '[' << linea << ']';
            while (ss >> linea)
                std::cout << "[ ][" << linea << ']';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/btxG40rkqyPpyGl3)</kbd>.

Comment: +1. Y solo he leído la primera línea de tu respuesta.

Comment: +1. Y sólo leí el comentario de Trauma.

Comment: +1. Y sólo quería seguir la cadena.